# Scaffold generated rspec controller test returns nil on Factory created model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Even when the following line works just fine on the model test:

```
game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
```

It doesn't seem to do it on games_controller_rspec.rb.

```
describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all games as @games" do
      game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
      get :index, {}
      expect(assigns(:games)).to eq([game])
    end
end
```

And I keep getting "expected: [...]
            got: nil"

This is the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :game do |f|
    f.team_a_id { 1 }
    f.team_b_id { 2 }
  end
end
```

Full games_controller.rb:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :check_admin_status, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @games = Game.all
end

def show
end

def new
    @game = Game.new
end

def edit
end

def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

respond_to do |format|
    if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @game }
    else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

end

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
        if @game.update(game_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
    else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end

end

def destroy
    @game.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to games_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
    def set_game
      @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

    def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:team_a_id, :team_b_id)
    end
end
```

Full games_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GamesController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  let(:valid_attributes) { { "team_a_id" => "1" } }
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all games as @games" do
      game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
      get :index, {}
      expect(assigns(:games)).to eq([game])
    end
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "assigns the requested game as @game" do
      game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
      get :show, {:id => game.to_param}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:game)).to eq(game)
    end
  end

  describe "GET new" do
    it "assigns a new game as @game" do
      get :new, {}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:game)).to be_a_new(Game)
    end
  end

  describe "GET edit" do
    it "assigns the requested game as @game" do
      game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
      get :edit, {:id => game.to_param}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:game)).to eq(game)
    end
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Game" do
        expect {
          post :create, {:game => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        }.to change(Game, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created game as @game" do
        post :create, {:game => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:game)).to be_a(Game)
        expect(assigns(:game)).to be_persisted
      end

      it "redirects to the created game" do
        post :create, {:game => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(response).to redirect_to(Game.last)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved game as @game" do
        allow_any_instance_of(Game).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create, {:game => { "team_a_id" => "invalid value" }}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:game)).to be_a_new(Game)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
        allow_any_instance_of(Game).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create, {:game => { "team_a_id" => "invalid value" }}, valid_session
        expect(response).to render_template("new")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "PUT update" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested game" do
        game = Game.create! valid_attributes
        expect_any_instance_of(Game).to receive(:update).with({ "team_a_id" => "1" })
        put :update, {:id => game.to_param, :game => { "team_a_id" => "1" }}, valid_session
      end

      it "assigns the requested game as @game" do
        game = Game.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => game.to_param, :game => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:game)).to eq(game)
      end

      it "redirects to the game" do
        game = Game.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => game.to_param, :game => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(response).to redirect_to(game)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns the game as @game" do
        game = Game.create! valid_attributes
        allow_any_instance_of(Game).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        put :update, {:id => game.to_param, :game => { "team_a_id" => "invalid value" }}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:game)).to eq(game)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
        game = Game.create! valid_attributes
        allow_any_instance_of(Game).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        put :update, {:id => game.to_param, :game => { "team_a_id" => "invalid value" }}, valid_session
        expect(response).to render_template("edit")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested game" do
      game = Game.create! valid_attributes
      expect {
        delete :destroy, {:id => game.to_param}, valid_session
      }.to change(Game, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to the games list" do
      game = Game.create! valid_attributes
      delete :destroy, {:id => game.to_param}, valid_session
      expect(response).to redirect_to(games_url)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: we would need to see your controller code - is it actually defining `@games` for the view?

Comment: Yes it is, sevenseacat:
    
    def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

Comment: can you post the *full* controller and *full* spec?

Comment: Just did it. Hope it's helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. The problem was with user privileges. I'm using devise and only allow certain methods to regular users. Therefore the result for them would be nil, unless i take the test with an admin user.
Basically I had to set an admin user on spec to make it work.

This is how you do it:

1) Write controller_macros.rb inside spec/support

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin) # Using factory girl as an example
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      user.confirm! 
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

2) Add it to spec_helper

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

3) Set the user to admin on your controller_spec

```
describe GamesController do
    login_admin

    describe "GET index" do
        game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
        get :index, {}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:games).to eq([game])
    end
```

My User factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email "nn@nnn.com"
        password "12345654321"
        password_confirmation { "12345654321" }
        factory :admin do
            after(:create) { |user| user.update_attribute :admin, true }
        end
    end
end
```

Founded [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same exact issue. I found a post on here (I forgot to bookmark it and am having trouble finding it) that said to replace your "get :index, {}" with "controller.index" and see if it works. It worked for me when I did this. They also said it was a routing issue. What I don't understand is why, and how to fix it so that I can use the standard code that's generated from the scaffold. My route tests pass, but yet there's a routing issue that's causing "get" not to work in these tests? I don't understand.

EDIT:

Just found the post. Check it out [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384268/rspec-test-of-my-controller-returns-nil-factory-girl) The OP never comes back to tell what the issue was our how they fixed it though. I would love to know as I'm frustrated trying to figure out how to get this working.

Comment: Thanks, i will check the routing, in case it's something related. But changing it to controller.index is not doing it for me.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. That actually did the trick. But the routing is ok, so i don't really know what's the problem..