# Rspec testing devise failing because assigns always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm having controller test with devise, but it always fail because assigns always return nil, please help to find where the problem is, thanks a million!

posts_controller_spec.rb:

```
RSpec.describe PostsController, :type => :controller do
   describe "with valid session" do
      describe "GET index" do
         it "assigns all posts as @posts" do
            sign_in :admin, @user
            post = create(:post)
            get :index, {}
            expect(assigns(:posts)).to eq([post])
         end
      end
   end
   ...
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   # GET /posts
   # GET /posts.json
   def index
     @posts = Post.all
   end
   ...
end
```

I've included devise test helpers in spec/rails_helper.rb

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
```

In my case, post is scoped under admin, not sure if that makes difference (functional test doesn't get through routes?), so I just include my routes.rb here

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root to: 'home#index'
   get 'admin', to: 'admin#index'
   devise_for :users
   scope '/admin' do
     resources :posts
   end
end
```

And finally, the output from rspec:

```
1) PostsController with valid session GET index assigns all posts as @posts
   Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:posts)).to eq([post])

   expected: [#<Post id: 57, title: "MyText", body: "MyText", image_url: "MyString", created_at: "2014-09-02 14:36:01", updated_at: "2014-09-02 14:36:01", user_id: 1>]
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've read this thread [rspec test of my controller returns nil (+factory girl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384268/rspec-test-of-my-controller-returns-nil-factory-girl) , and followed the suggestion to change `get :index` to `controller.index` . The suggestion is that if that passes the test then it's a routing problem. It does pass the test, but I still have no idea where the routing problem is, and why the `get :index` is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a small mistake: create an user before using devise sign_in

```
RSpec.describe PostsController, :type => :controller do

   describe "with valid session" do

     let (:user) { create(:user) }

      describe "GET index" do
         it "assigns all posts as @posts" do
           sign_in user
           post = create(:post)
           get :index, {}
           expect(assigns(:posts)).to eq([post])
         end
         ...
      end
   end
end
```